# "invite friends via email" feature...what security implications should i concerned about?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm adding a feature to my site to allow people to invite their friends.  I was going to accept a commma-separated list and allow them to import their Gmail contacts.

My question is, how do i prevent someone from just posting a string of emails to my script and essentially A) overwhelming my mailserver or B) spamming a bunch of people.  Obviously, captcha would help with this, but just curious if there's other ways to limit our risk...

Since the contacts/etc are all on the front end, there's no way to hash it using our sites encryption key...so my initial thought of hashing the emails before sending them to our "sender" script probably wont work...

Any advice, help or direction on this is much appreciated!

Comment: captcha, session limit, ip limit, time limit.

Comment: Well as you said you will atleast need good Captcha, like reCAPTCHA: http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost: Don't use a generic sender script! Any script that takes recipients and a message body from an external request is a security issue. Security is hard and you will make mistakes, opening you up to spammer. Better create several scripts that are only capable of sending a specific e-mail. E.g. a contact-us script that is hardcoded or preconfigured to send e-mail only to you. A tell-a-friend script that has a hardcoded or preconfigured message template in it.

Next, you need to be very careful about putting anything supplied by your users into an e-mail header (this includes message subjects, from/reply-to addresses, etcetera). Of course, it's nice to set the reply-to automatically to the user's e-mail address, but what if I type this as my e-mail address:

```
me@example.org\nBCC:spam-target@example.org
```

Now I'm spamming other people through your contact form, even though that form is only supposed to send mail to you.

You should treat anything that a user can put in a mail header (or message) as suspicious as you'd treat anything that goes in an SQL query.

Comment: this is great advice, i thank you very much! this is the advice i was looking for!